# Show that $A\sin(\omega t) + B\cos(\omega t)$ can be rewritten $a\sin(\omega t+\phi) + b\cos(\omega t+\phi)$ where $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal vectors

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, dynamical-systems

This is all in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Show that $\vec{A}\sin(\omega t) + \vec{B}\cos(\omega t)$ can be rewritten as $\vec{a}\sin(\omega t + \phi) + \vec{b}\cos(\omega t + \phi)$ where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are orthogonal vectors and $\phi$ is a constant phase

I tried expanding out the addition in sin and cos and got that $\vec{A} = \vec{a}\cos\phi- \vec{b}\sin\phi$ and $\vec{B} = \vec{a}\sin\phi+ \vec{b}\cos\phi$ but I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: So your inputs are $\vec A$ and $\vec B$, and you want to find $\vec a$, $\vec b$, and $\phi$?

Comment: More just showing they exists but finding them would work too

Comment: $\vec a,\vec b$ are the main axis of the ellipse generated by $\vec A,\vec B$.

Comment: Thanks but that's actually the next part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you found that the pair $(\vec A,\vec B)$ is a "rotation" of the pair $(\vec a,\vec b)$ (an application of a rotation matrix to the pair as 2-column matrix). You can rotate that back,
$$
\vec a=\vec A\cos\phi+\vec B\sin\phi\\
\vec b=-\vec A\sin\phi+\vec B\cos\phi
$$
Now the condition for orthogonality leads to an equation for $\phi$,
$$
0=\langle\vec A,\vec B\rangle\cos(2\phi)-\frac12(|\vec A|^2-|\vec B|^2)\sin(2\phi),
$$
where you can easily show that it has a real solution.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for the help

Comment: "is a rotation" is not correct. $\vec A,\vec B$ are not necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: I think it would still work though as the transformation is invertible? Just not a rotation

Comment: Yep, this is why I only pointed at the expression.